# How to stop IIS returning 502.3 - Bad Gateway when ASP.Net Core returns 413 (Request body too large)?

Tags: asp.net, iis, asp.net-core, iis-express, kestrel-http-server

I have a ASP.Net core site.

I have set a custom max request size.

Either:

```
 app.Use(async (context, next) =>
     {
         int limit = 1024;
         context.Features.Get<IHttpMaxRequestBodySizeFeature>().MaxRequestBodySize = limit;
         await next.Invoke();
     });
```

Or using the attribute `[RequestSizeLimit(1024)]`

When I host the site as a standalone console app it works correctly; returning `413` when I `POST` a payload larger than 1k (*in this example*).

However when I deploy to be hosted on IIS or run from within IIS express I get:

> HTTP Error 502.3 - Bad Gateway

---

Here is an example controller which triggers the problem:

```
[Route("api/values")]
public class ValuesController : Controller
{
    // POST api/values
    [HttpPost]
    [RequestSizeLimit(1024)]
    public IActionResult Post()
    {
        string echo= "";
        try
        {
            using (StreamReader sr= new StreamReader(Request.Body))
            {
                echo = sr.ReadToEnd();
            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            return StatusCode(413);
        }
        return StatusCode(200, echo);
    }
}
```

*I don't know if reading from the Body stream makes a difference. But because of reasons, I need to save the body verbatim to the Db. So it's a problem either way*

I have tried:

1. Catching the exception and swallowing it in the controller
2. Catching the exception and re-throwing it in the controller
3. Catching the exception and swallowing it in the middleware pipeline

They all have then same problem.

Not setting a `RequestSizeLimit` and returning `413` works correctly through IIS though.

So I think it is something to do with how Kestral passes back a response when it threw an exception internally...

**What is going on exactly?**

**How do I get IIS/Kestral to play nice?**

Comment: @LexLi Are you saying I will find that I am look for there or I should log an issue?